# How to play an audio (phone number) on javaScript?

Tags: javascript, audio, timeout, settimeout, wav

I need to create a function that sounds the digits of a phone number, one by one.
I have created that function but it doesn't work well. 
The first time I clicked the button , it called the function and it sounded the digits very well. Right after it I wanted to hear the phone number again and it just said a few digits of the phone number.
I debugged and saw that it works well when I am in debug mode (I heard the whole phone number and not just few digits from it).
I think that the  setTimeout function just doesn't work well and I think that I should change my function and sound the phone number in a different way.

Here is the code:

```
this.PlayVoiceNumber = function (phone) {
    if (phone.length > 0 && this.VoiceNumberPlaying == false) {
        phone = phone.replace('-', '');
        var numberIndex = 0,
            mediaPath = '/Services/VoiceFolder/',
            extension = '',
            trackCount = phone.length,
            currentNumber = '';

        $('#audioPlayer').bind('play', function () {
            this.VoiceNumberPlaying = true;
        });

        $('#audioPlayer').bind('pause', function () {
            this.VoiceNumberPlaying = false;
        });

        id = 0;
        currentNumber = phone[id];

        audio = $('#audioPlayer');
        audioPlayer.src = mediaPath + currentNumber + ".wav";

        $('#audioPlayer').bind('ended', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                id++;
                if (phone.length > id) {
                    currentNumber = phone[id];
                    audioPlayer.src = mediaPath + currentNumber + ".wav";
                    audioPlayer.load();
                    audioPlayer.play();
                }
            }, 200);
        });
        audioPlayer.load();
        audioPlayer.play();
    }
}
```

/// Information

'phone' - It is the phone number it self.
"phone = phone.replace('-', '')" - the phone number comes like this -"03-6777777"
 "audioPlayer.src = mediaPath + currentNumber + ".wav"" - this is the location of the digit audio .
///

I have tried to change the time for the time out function but it didn't help.
So I would like you to help me create a new function or just to fix or replace the "setTimeout" function.
Thank you very much (:

Comment: Your `setTimeout` indeed looks unreliable. Would it be hard to make a test case on jsFiddle? I find this problem interesting, but you didn't even mention what framework you use for audio.

Comment: I have no idea what is jsFiddle.
And how can I check what framework Im using for audio?

Comment: You had to include some scripts to allow you to use Audio like that. Normal web audio API is more complex to use. jsFiddle is website where you can make example scripts to show people what problem you have: https://jsfiddle.net/ You can also include scripts there, using the left panel.

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean. 
Maybe its this :
<audio id="audioPlayer" src="/Services/VoiceFolder/2.wav">
        <source src="/Services/VoiceFolder/1.wav" type="audio/wav">
        <source src="/Services/VoiceFolder/2.wav" type="audio/wav">
        <source src="/Services/VoiceFolder/3.wav" type="audio/wav">
        <source src="/Services/VoiceFolder/4.wav" type="audio/wav">
  ....
    </audio>